# how to add a custom htmlDependency in `bookdown::gitbook`

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

`bookdown::gitbook()` adds the content of https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/tree/master/inst/resources/gitbook as a `htmltools::htmlDependency`. How can I add such a custom dependency to a gitbook?

The goal is to provide an easy way to add a corporate css (including images). The definition of the `htmlDependency()` and all the required files would reside in an R package.

Comment: This question may be related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320325/how-to-include-css-code-in-asis-output .  It's not quite the same problem, but it looks as though you can't use `htmlDependency` to simply add a CSS file.

Comment: Have a look at how R packages like `tufte` or `tint` ship their CSS files.

Comment: `tufte` and `tint` both define their own render function. Going that path would have me to copy and slightly modify `bookdown::gitbook` as well as all the non exported functions that `bookdown::gitbook` uses. There should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The `...` arguments of `bookdown::gitbook()` are eventually passed to `rmarkdown::html_document()`, which are further passed to `rmarkdown::html_document_base()`, which has an `extra_dependencies` argument. You can create your list of dependencies with `htmltools::htmlDependency()`, and pass them to `bookdown::gitbook()` via the `extra_dependencies` argument.